# odoo - display name of many2one field combination of 2 fields

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

In my module i have the following many2one field:
`'xx_insurance_type': fields.many2one('xx.insurance.type', string='Insurance')`

where `xx.insurance.type` is the following:

```
class InsuranceType(osv.Model):
    _name='xx.insurance.type'

    _columns = {
        'name' : fields.char(size=128, string = 'Name'),
        'sale_ids': fields.one2many('sale.order', 'xx_insurance_type', string = 'Sale orders'),
        'insurance_percentage' : fields.float('Insurance cost in %')
    }
```

I know the many2one field takes the *name* field as its display name but I would like to have it use the combination of `name` and `insurance_percentage` in the form of `name + " - " + insurance_percentage + "%"`

I read it is best to overwrite the `get_name` method so I tried the following:

```
def get_name(self,cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
        ids = [ids]

    res = []
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
         name = record.name
         percentage = record.insurance_percentage
         res.append(record.id, name + " - " + percentage + "%")
    return res
```

and placed this inside the ÌnsuranceType` class.
Since nothing happened:
Do i have to place it inside the main class containing the field? If so, is there an other way to do this since that will probably also change the display ways of the other many2one fields?

Comment: The name of the method is `name_get` instead of `get_name`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't want to alter the display name of the rest of the `many2one` related to the model `xx.insurance.type`, you can add a context in the XML view to the `many2one` whose display name you want to modify:

```
<field name="xx_insurance_type" context="{'special_display_name': True}"/>
```

And then, in your `name_get` function:

```
def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
        ids = [ids]
    res = []
    if context.get('special_display_name', False):
        for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            name = record.name
            percentage = record.insurance_percentage
            res.append(record.id, name + " - " + percentage + "%")
    else:
        # Do a for and set here the standard display name, for example if the standard display name were name, you should do the next for
        for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            res.append(record.id, record.name)
    return res
```

Comment: Unfortunately it also *sets* the name of the records, so it messes up my database.

Comment: one of the most great answer thank you for the information

Comment: simplest answer is in the Yenthe Van Ginneken coment here: https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/using-name-get-how-to-shows-two-different-display-values-2589

Comment: not working for many2one field which is present in one2many field.

Answer (score 0):

```
@api.depends('name', 'insurance_percentage')
    def name_get(self):
        res = []
        for record in self:
            name = record.name
            if record.insurance_percentage:
                name = '[' + record.insurance_percentage+ ']' + name
            res.append((record.id, name))
        return res
```