# Display different field's value instead of 'name' field in of many2one

Tags: odoo-8, many-to-one

There are 3 country fields  which are many2one. As per current behaviour, in 3 fields it is displaying country names. I just want to display short code of that country in one of that field. How can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [odoo - display name of many2one field combination of 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724556/odoo-display-name-of-many2one-field-combination-of-2-fields)

Comment: Thanks. You solved my problem!