# Odoo using name_get how to shows two different display values?

Tags: python, odoo

In the Tour Form:-

Currently display

Hotel  --> Hotel Name with Ville Name

In the Tour Tree view:-

Hotel  --> Hotel Name with Ville Name

Actual Requirement

In the Tour Form:-

Hotel  --> Hotel Name with Ville Name

In the Tour Tree view:-

Hotel  --> Hotel Name

```
class obj_ghotel(osv.osv):
    _name = "obj.ghotel"
    _description = "Objet ghotel"
    _rec_name = "nom_hotel"

    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        res = []
        for asset in self:
                res.append((asset.id,asset.nom_hotel + ' - ' + asset.id_ville.nom))
        return res
     _columns = {
        'nom_hotel': fields.char("Nom d'hotel", required=True),
        'id_ville': fields.many2one('obj.ville', 'ville', selection=_get_selection),
    }
```

pics:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [odoo - display name of many2one field combination of 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724556/odoo-display-name-of-many2one-field-combination-of-2-fields)

Comment: @forvas i'm using the new api

Comment: You have all declared with the old API except for the `name_get` method... I think you can't use the new API if your model is inheriting from `osv.osv`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with context. On the field in form view pass some context, check context value in name_get method, if satisfied then only pass ville nom.