# How to manage a different display name for two Many2one pointing to the same model in Odoo 11?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I am  going to put a simple example:

I have two *Many2one* fields, `dog_name`, `dog_alias`, both of them pointing to the `dog` model. This model has the *Char* fields `name` and `alias`.

When I open the dropdown of `dog_name`, I should see the name of the dogs, when I open the dropdown of `dog_alias`, I shouls see the alias of the dogs.

For instance, I have a record of `dog` with ID *57*, name *Fox* and alias *Foxito*, if I open the dropdown of `dog_name`, I should see *Fox*, if I open the dropdown of `dog_alias`, I should see *Foxito*. But if I select any of them, the record selected will be the same (the one with ID *57*).

To manage this behaviour, I always used `name_get` combined with a XML context:

[odoo - display name of many2one field combination of 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724556/odoo-display-name-of-many2one-field-combination-of-2-fields)

However, this time the following is happening: when I deploy the `dog_alias` dropdown, I see *Foxito*, which works great, but when I save the record, I see *Fox*. I guess because that is the `display_name` of the model, but if I do this:

**Python**

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('name', 'alias')
def _compute_display_name(self):
    for dog in self:
        if self._context.get('display_name', False) == 'alias':
            dog.display_name = dog.alias
        else:
            dog.display_name = dog.name

display_name = fields.Char(
    compute='_compute_display_name',
)
dog_name = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='dog',
    string='Dog Names',
    required=True
)
dog_alias = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='dog',
    string='Dog Aliases'
)
```

**XML**

```
<field name="dog_name"/>
<field name="dog_alias" context="{'display_name': 'alias'}"/>
```

The problem is still the same. The `context` in the `_compute_display_name` method never brings the one I set in the XML file, therefore, if I select *Foxito* in the `dog_alias` field, after saving I see *Fox* in that field, which is not what I want.

So, do you have any idea of how to solve this situation?

Comment: Show us how you define those fields.

Comment: Problem here is that the compute method is called before the rendering of the view, so there won't be any context from the view on computation. I've struggeled about this so often, but never found a solution, without doing some dirty things.

Comment: Do you want to be able to select 2 different dogs? Or do you want to display 2 different fields of the same referenced dog?

Comment: @miw I want to be able to select two different dogs (but I could select the same dog in both fields). However, in one field I want to see names and in the other aliases.

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas I've updated the Python code to show the definition of both fields.