# odoo11 Many2one display different name in two different fields

Tags: odoo-11

I need two different m2o fields to display different names from a database.

I refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724556/odoo-display-name-of-many2one-field-combination-of-2-fields) and use context to note, but can't get the context in name_get function.

*.xml

```xml
<field name="car_no" context="{'special_display_name': 'carno'}"/>

<field name="processing_attache" context="{'special_display_name': 'process'}"/>
```

*.py

```py
class A
    car_no = fields.Many2one("yc.weight", string="car no")
    processing_attache = fields.Many2one("yc.weight.details", "processing name")

class B

    @api.multi
    def name_get(self, context= None):
        if context is None:
            context={}
        result = []
        if context.get('special_display_name','carno'):    
            for record in self:    
                name = record.carno
                result.append((record.id, name))
        elif context.get('special_display_name','process'):
            for record in self:
                name = record.processing_id
                result.append((record.id, name))
        return result
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: You want to gave different name to both many2one field?

Comment: yes, I overwrite name_get function, and it passed just one name.

Comment: Override name_get()  for both models 'yc.weight' and 'yc.weight.details' then it will show both name differently.

Comment: what if "processing_attache" is many2one "yc.weight"? two fields many2one same db. how can I get different name in same name_get function?

Comment: You want different name for both fields means different name for car_no and processing_attache so you have to override their name_get function in their respective models for showing their names in other models.

Comment: Thanks for response.